# image source with variable

Tags: php, html

Is this wrong ?

```
<img src="frame_src/"<?php echo $frameid ?>".png"/>
```

Where the $frameid equals to a number i.e.= 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<img src="frame_src/<?php echo $frameid ?>.png"/>
```

I removed the two quotes (")

Depending on your set up you might also be able to do this...

```
<img src="frame_src/<?=$frameid ?>.png"/>
```

Comment: No worries, perhaps you can make the answer as accepted. Thanks